# Stop Automatic Checking Checkbox

Tags: android

I made an activity that has a list with my apps. Each item of the list has a checkbox.

```
private PackageManager gestorPacotes;
private List<Aplicacao> listaAplicacoes;
private ListView lista;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lista_aplicacoes);
    carregaAplicacoes();
    carregaListaAplicacoes();
}

private void carregaAplicacoes(){
    gestorPacotes = getPackageManager();
    listaAplicacoes = new ArrayList<Aplicacao>();

    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

    List<ResolveInfo> availableActivities = gestorPacotes.queryIntentActivities(i, 0);
    for(ResolveInfo ri:availableActivities) {
        Aplicacao aplicacao = new Aplicacao();
        aplicacao.nome = ri.loadLabel(gestorPacotes);
        aplicacao.pacote = ri.activityInfo.packageName;
        aplicacao.icon = ri.activityInfo.loadIcon(gestorPacotes);
        listaAplicacoes.add(aplicacao);
    }
}

private void carregaListaAplicacoes(){
    lista = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listaAplicacoes);

    ArrayAdapter<Aplicacao> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Aplicacao>(this, R.layout.list_item, listaAplicacoes) {
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if(convertView == null){
                convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            }

            ImageView appIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_app_icon);
            appIcon.setImageDrawable(listaAplicacoes.get(position).icon);

            final TextView appLabel = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_app_label);
            appLabel.setText(listaAplicacoes.get(position).nome);

            final TextView appName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_app_name);
            appName.setText(listaAplicacoes.get(position).pacote);

            final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.chk_box);
            checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),appLabel.getText(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            return convertView;
        }
    };
    lista.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

When I check one item of the list other elements are being checked automatically. What do I have to add to my code to this stop happening?
Thanks.

Comment: I think what's happening is by making checkBox `final`, it is holding one reference for every single checkbox in the adapter. Remove the `final` keyword from inside the adapter and try it.

Comment: i would rather go with `setOnCheckedChangeListener` with the `Checkbox`and there you can go with the boolean value

Comment: @McAdam331 it continue to check automatically other checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use a RecyclerView for that kind of list, here's a good example on using RecyclerView in MultiChoice mode.https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/recyclerview-part-2-choice-modes/